# angular.js:14800 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2019-12-29` to be a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my data field like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Enter Expiry Date</label>
    <input type="date" ng-model="product.expiryDate"></input>
    <p class="help-block"></p> 
</div>
```

Input date format looks like: **dd-mm-yyyy** , 
And my controller looks like:

```
 app.controller('xyz', function(){
    $scope.product = productService.getProduct(id);  //rough code
});
```

So, this is setting all other input fields except date and angular giving error as mentioned in title. Even i checked that my date format inside product like:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(product.expiryDate));
```

It shows date format as: **yyyy-mm-dd**.

1. My problem is why i am getting error like: **angular.js:14800 Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2019-12-29` to be a date** ?
2. Is there any other way to solve problem?

Comment: try adding `$scope.product.expiryDate = new Date($scope.product.expiryDate);` to convert it to Date object

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked for me !!. Can you explain me what was the problem without above code. Still i was getting required date format. then why error>

Comment: `"2019-12-29"` is just text, but [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is an object that input of type 'date' accepts. Otherwise Angularjs can't parse it correctly

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: ngModel:datefmt](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt).

Answer (score 1):

From `input[date]` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D):

> **The model must always be a Date object, otherwise AngularJS will throw an error**. Invalid Date objects (dates whose `getTime()` is `NaN`) will be rendered as an empty string.